# MAC address in android phone

Tags: android

I build an android app with Android Studio  with Java  and I want to get the mac address from the phone 
limit user any action do and somethings else 
who can help me?
 my code is this but didnt work

```
 private void getmacadres() {

        String macAddress =
                android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), "android_id");


        Toast.makeText(G.Context, macAddress, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Is you add in androidManifest : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

Comment: What did you mean by "limit user any action do and somethings"?

Answer (score 3):

add this permission to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

and use this:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) 
getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();
```

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this problem by using this

```
    private String deviceId() {
    return Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
}
```